# Multi-peak distribution fit in matlab

Tags: matlab, distribution, data-fitting

I've got a distribution that consists of two overlapping, unimodal populations, and I want to find the parameters of a custom PDF function.  For the time being, I'm working with a simulated dataset consisting of two normal distributions (though my experimental dataset consists of normal+lognormal populations).  Google and MatLab Help lead me to the following:

```
norm=randn(1000,1)+3;
norm2=randn(2000,1)+7;
x=combine(norm,norm2);

pdf_normmixture = @(x,p,mu1,mu2,sigma1,sigma2)p*normpdf(x,mu1,sigma1) + (1-p)*normpdf(x,mu2,sigma2);
pStart = .25;
muStart = [3 7];
sigmaStart = sqrt(var(x) - .25*diff(muStart).^2);
start = [pStart muStart sigmaStart sigmaStart];
lb = [0 -Inf -Inf 0 0];
ub = [1 Inf Inf Inf Inf];
options = statset('MaxIter',1000, 'MaxFunEvals',2000);
paramEsts = mle(x, 'pdf',pdf_normmixture, 'start',start, 'lower',lb, 'upper',ub, 'options',options);

scale=.25;
bins = min(x):scale:max(x);
h = bar(bins,histc(x,bins)/(length(x)*scale),'histc');
xgrid = linspace(1.1*min(x),1.1*max(x),200);
pdfgrid = pdf_normmixture(xgrid,paramEsts(1),paramEsts(2),paramEsts(3),paramEsts(4),paramEsts(5));
hold on
plot(xgrid,pdfgrid,'-')
hold off
xlabel('x')
ylabel('Probability Density')
```

This works perfectly until the population sizes diverge... 1000:3000 is around the limit with MaxFunEvals = 2000.  Anything higher can't be rescued by simply changing the pStart value or reasonably increasing MaxIter or MaxFunEvals.  How can I fix this? Could it be a problem with the way I'm setting sigmaStart?  Is it simply an issue of increasing population size?

I run into even more problems when I try to substitute one of the normpdf terms for lognpdf (with appropriate changes to muStart guesses), but that's a different set of questions entirely.  Is there a better way?

Regards,